# Dynamically decomposing and assembling tuples

Tags: scala

I have some code that involves verifying the existence of keys/values in a user-generated Map, which is resulting in many levels of nested code. TypeSafe's Slick framework has a really clean way of loading a database result into a list of tuples ex:

```
Q.queryNA[Tuple3[Int,String,Double]]("SELECT post_id,post_title,post_score FROM posts").list
```

I was thinking this syntax could be a clean way to verify and pattern match multiple fields in one go ex:

```
parseMap[Tuple3[Int,String,Double]](map_in,"post_id","post_title","post_score") match {
    ((post_id,post_title,post_score)) => //...do processing
    _ => println("one or more fields were missing or could not be parsed to datatype")
}
```

I've been trying to work through this problem, but I may be in over my head. My *pseudocode* might look something like this (for now lets assume the map will validate to keep the code simple)

```
def parseMap[T<:Product](map_in: Map[Any],fields: String*) = {
     val head = Tuple1(map_in(fields.head).as[classOf[T._1]])
     if(T.isInstanceOf[Tuple1[_]]) head else head ++ parseMap[T(1->arity)](map_in,fields.tail)
}
```

So, obviously this code won't come close to compiling. The main issues being
1. T is the template type, not a value, so classOf will not work with it.
2. decoupling the remaining elements of the Tuple (and their datatypes), then re-concatenating them.

It seems like there is a lot of stuff going on here that isn't possible to do, but since the Slick framework does it there must be a way. I tried reading their github code for the queryNA method, but it was beyond my level of expertise.

Another syntax I've considered, though not the same as the Slick syntax is to write a def that returns a Product object, and takes in a list of field name and datatype tuples ex.

```
List("post_id"->Int,"post_title"->String,"post_score"->Double)
```

Though that still doesn't solve my underlying problem of having to dynamically assemble a tuple.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve here. It looks like it has something to do with nested maps, or maybe indexing into JSON or XML like structures, but it's quite hard to tell. Could you show some examples of possible inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: Yes, you are correct I am trying to parse JSON, but for now I am only dealing with one-level json. The trick is more in handling the different datatypes. I can read the json object like a map, but must call .as[Int] or .as[String] depending on the field (so using the example above the input might look like: {"post_id":50,post_title:"My Post","post_score":4.5}. I was hoping to validate all these fields in one go and pattern math for a resulting tuple, in this case it would be a Tuple3[Int,String,Double].

Comment: Have you looked at [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/)?

Comment: Argonaut looks promising -- I'll check it out. Thanks!